# Are yetis for real? Do Himalayan yetis preserve bodies of sadhus who attain samadhi?

Tags: samadhi, yogi

Most of us heard about yetis. I think they are real.

But if they're real:

1. **Why don't they appear to others?**
2. **What exactly is their purpose?**

We don't know but there are proofs captured time and again of their existence mostly in the Himalayan region. This species is always hidden from the society.

I have a belief that if they are protecting their secrecy of their existence that may be due to any religious reasons. We have also heard that the yogis or sadhus choose Himalayas to do the sadhana (meditation) and there are many sadhus who are into that state which we can't even imagine. From there are many states and there is a one state called samadhi in which a person's soul left his or her body and when they left their body for too long only the Himalayan below 0 degree temperature helps to preserve their body but what about if somebody reached there and see sadhu's body.

I think that is the reason that there are yetis who prevent their bodies so no one could reach there.

Answer (score 5):

We do not know exactly whether yeti exists or not or knowing its existence has nothing to do with Spirituality or knowing Supreme Brahman. However, i will provide opinion of an old Tibetian Yogi, as mentioned in the book "[Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master](https://www.amazon.in/Apprenticed-Himalayan-Master-Yogis-Autobiography-ebook/dp/B007F2I3F0)" by [Sri M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Madhukarnath).

Sri M asks wandering Tibetian Monk a question about Yeti.

> “Two more questions Sir, if I may?” I said.
>
> “Go ahead”
>
> “Some books say that hidden away in certain parts of Tibet, there are
>   remains of old extraterrestrial civilizations, is that true? Secondly,
>   does the Yeti, the abominable snowman, really exist? Have you seen
>   one?”
>
> “To the first question,,” said the Tibetan yogi, “yes, there are such
>   places, and I have myself seen such a cave in an almost inaccessible
>   part of Tibet. There, I have seen, well-preserved bodies of small
>   built humanoids, with skulls larger than ours, and a dark almost
>   grayish complexion. However, we believe that they are an ancient race
>   from the earth itself, and not from some other planet or galaxy. Our
>   teachers say that this particular race was destroyed by a war between
>   two rival civilizations that had both evolved to great heights
>   intellectually, and ignored the feelings of love and compassion
>   totally. The way our present civilization is progressing, one wonders
>   what fate awaits us.
>
> “Now, regarding the Yeti – well, it exists, although many reported
>   sightings may be false. On the ancient route to Kailash from
>   Badrinath, across the Mana pass which is now almost never used, there
>   exists an old Buddhist monastery called Tholingmutt on the Tibetan
>   side. In the caves not far from Tholingmutt, some Lamas have sighted
>   the Yeti even recently. I have seen one myself. Ask Babaji if he could
>   take you to Tholingmutt or even to Kailash. He is quite familiar with
>   the route, and has been there many times. Maybe you will see a Yeti
>   too.”

Regarding reason, we don't know exactly what kind of living being it is. So, let's not speculate on it.

Comment: "although many reported sightings may be false" – followed by – "I have seen one myself." is very spurious.

Comment: @sv. Let's consider an example of uncontacted tribal people. If one such tribal man accidentally comes to a city and sees a mobile phone (consider a high end phone) and he wonders seeing it. He goes back to his tribe and says what he saw. Many of his tribe may or may not believe his words. Even some pranksters in his tribe say they have seen such a device (phone) in thier forest. But this man says to new person (assume someone in tribe) "although many reported sightings may be false" – followed by – "I have seen one myself"", **which is not at all spurious**.